# inner class in AS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

for example:

```
 package{
    public class A {
       var test:String;
       public function A()
       }

}
 class B{

}
```

the code is in the same file, we call B is inner class, then how to call the constructor of class B

Comment: your class B has no constructor in the above definition.

Comment: You don't need to define a constructor function, it's optional.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
package
{
    public class A 
    {
       var test:String;

       public function A()
       {
          var b:B = new B();
       }
    }
}
class B
{
   public function B()
   {
       trace('class B');
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this really function as an inner class?  For example, can class B access private members of class A in this setup?