# What is the jython pythonic equivalent to anonymous inner classes ie x.addCallback(new Callback() ) { .... }

Tags: java, python, jython

Some java language constructs rely upon anonymous inner classes being added to an abstract class at run time in order to fill in the omitted functions at run time.

For example,

[Example of inner classes used as an alternative to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126636/example-of-inner-classes-used-as-an-alternative-to-interfaces)

How would you do this in jython? Is it possible to do or would you have to write out the class in its entirety and then reference it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Jython, can I make an inline anonymous class that implements a Java interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12424405/in-jython-can-i-make-an-inline-anonymous-class-that-implements-a-java-interface)

Comment: Thanks Anders ... Yes that is pretty much what I was looking for.